# Нужно сделать метод бана и из бана игроков в классе Юзер

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    //    Помогите я ТУПОЙ !
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool working = true;
            int userInput = 0;
            UserBase userBase = new UserBase();

            while (working)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1- Показать базу игроков");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Добавить нового игрока в базу");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Удалить игрока по номеру в базе");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - бан игрока по номеру в базе");
                Console.WriteLine("5 - убрать бан игрока по номеру в базе");
                Console.WriteLine("0 - Выход");
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        userBase.ShowAllUsers();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите имя нового игрока");
                        string userName = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите уровень нового игрока");
                        int userLevel = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        userBase.AddNewUser(userName, userLevel, false);
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер игрока которого нужно удалить из базы");
                        int deliteUser = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        userBase.DeliteUser(deliteUser);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер игрока которого нужно банить");
                        int banUser = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        userBase.BanUser(banUser);
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер игрока которого нужно убрать бан");
                        int unBanUser = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        userBase.UnBanUser(unBanUser);
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        working = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        class UserBase
        {

            private List<User> _users = new List<User>();
            public void AddNewUser(string name, int lvl, bool ban)
            {
                _users.Add(new User(name, lvl, ban));
            }

            public void ShowAllUsers()
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < _users.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_users[i]._ban == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"№-{i + 1} - Имя игрока - {_users[i]._name} - Уровень игрока - {_users[i]._level} - Игрок в бане");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"№-{i + 1} - Имя игрока - {_users[i]._name} - Уровень игрока - {_users[i]._level} - Игрок не в бане");
                    }
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            }
            public void DeliteUser(int userNumber)
            {
                _users.Remove(_users[userNumber - 1]);
            }
            public void BanUser(int userNumber)
            {
               //    У меня они тут но из за privite не вижу в другом классе
            }
            public void UnBanUser(int userNumber)
            {
                //    У меня они тут но из за privite не вижу в другом классе
            }

        }
        class User
        {

            public string _name { get; private set; }
            public int _level { get; private set; }
            public bool _ban
            {

                private set
                {
  
                }
                get
                {
                    return _ban;
                }

            }
            //    А по идеи эти 2 метода должны быть тут .

            public User(string name, int level, bool ban)
            {
                _name = name;
                _level = level;
                _ban = ban;
            }
            public User()
            {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня они тут, кто они?

Comment: ну методы . а их нужно в классе юзер сделать так как там _ban

Comment: Зачем, они и тут норм) Что не так с `_users[userNumber]._ban = true;`? Зачем приватный сеттер?

Comment: Я изучаю шарп и у меня задание. Остальные ошибки я исправил в вот это осталось .--  public bool Ban; - не используйте публичные переменные, для работы с баном сделайте методы бана и  р а з бана

Comment: И вот тут я туплю. Как передать в класс юзер того кого надо бан и вернуть значение. или вообще не так сделать. Короче я тупой и не могу понять ((

Comment: Ну сделайте методы) джависты какие-то задания писали) Зачем нужен кастомный сеттер, если есть нативный?)

Comment: То есть 2 метода я делаю в User ? и как мне передать туда значение кого в бан ? Я туплю и не могу понять. И у меня _users  тоже приват, то есть его тоже нужно будет изменить сеттером ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User {
 // ...
 public void   Ban() {_ban = true;}
 public void Unban() {_ban = false;}
}

class UserBase {
 // ...
 public void   Ban(int id) {_users[id-1].Ban();}
 public void Unban(int id) {_users[id-1].Unban();}
}
```

Comment: ну методы в классе Юзер. Пока не пойму почему не банит, ну  всё равно спасибо  буду дальше сам через F11 по шагам смотреть .

Comment: @vasya Ну так вам осталось только дописать проверку действия на наличие бана перед выполнением, это кажется в исходный вопрос не входило, логично?

Comment: Все получилось ! всем огромное Спасибо !